# Exchange 2013 Transport Agent service fails consitantly

Tags: exchange, exchange-2013

I'm running Windows Server 2012 R2 with Exchange 2013 w/ SP1. This computer is a member server of a AD2012R2 level domain. This server was also running SPAMfighter for Exchange.

Situation:
To become PCI compliant after the new regulations regarding POODLE attack vulnerability, I did two things.

1) I got a new SSL certificate reissued to the new encryption standard and installed it for Exchange and IIS.

1) I disabled SSLv3, made sure TLS1.0 was disabled, made sure TLS1.1 and 1.2 were both enabled. After disabling SSLv3, none of my Outlook clients could connect and OWA didn't work either. So I enabled SSLv3, Outlook clients and OWA began working. So I didn't think much else about, I would just get a second internet IP address and move my Exchange server traffic to that IP. The next day, I was informed that we were being inundated with spam email. So I opened up my SPAMfighter console, so my surprise none of the images were displayed. When I tried to log in to the console, I got all kinds of ASP .Net errors.

So here's where I'm at now. I removed SPAMfighter to hopes that reinstalling would correct the problem, it did not... but what it did do is kill my Transport Service. Now the transport service will no run, it will start and die. The event viewer shows this...

```
Failed to create agent factory for the agent 'SEMRoutingAgentReceive' with error 'Failed to create type SPAMfighter.Exchange.Platform.Exchange.Transport.Factory.Agent.SmtpReceiveAgentFactory' from assembly 'E:\SPAMfighter Enterprise\SPAMfighter Enterprise\Exchange\Transport\SPAMfighter.Exchange.Platform.Exchange.Transport.Factory.dll' due to error 'Invalid agent assembly path.'.'. Please verify the corresponding transport agent assembly and dependencies with correct version are installed.
```

From what I can gather, Exchange is trying to still load the transport module for SF, how do I remove that to get my Exchange Transport Service back online?

Thanks
Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the Exchange Management Shell and run

```
Get-TransportAgent
```

You should get a list of the transport agents running and hopefully the spam filter transport agent will be listed with a name that makes it clear that's what it is.

Then you can either,

```
Uninstall-TransportAgent “Name of the Agent”
```

or,

```
Disable-TransportAgent -Identity “Name of the Agent”
```

The former makes more sense in the context of uninstalling the spam filter. For either command, type verbatim or copy paste the name of the appropriate agent that you see in the list generated by Get-TransportAgent. Then try restarting the transport service.

Source:
http://johanveldhuis.nl/transport-agents-uitschakelenverwijderen/

Comment: Thank you that worked... now I just have to fix the main problem as to what has killed SPAMfighter.